# How do I insert a struct{} in a header file and call from source?

Tags: c, makefile, header-files

This is a very naive question, and I have searched a lot, but couldn't find answer due to my lazyness.

My source code functions are all in a file called lib.c and I have created a header file lib.h that I call in main.c. The problem arises when I have a struct{} inside the lib.c as the functions need the global struct object to be utilized locally.

Due to this complication, I have to include the lib.h inside the lib.c source file as well, because the struct{} is declared inside the lib.h.

If I take out the struct{} from the header file and place it within the lib.c file, the main.c cannot read the structure as it was not included in the lib.h.

```
lib.h

struct Structure {} structure;
void func1();
void func2();


lib.c

#include <stdio.h>
#...
void func1() {};
void func2() {};


main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#...
#include "lib.h"
int main() {};
```

Comment: What you want to do ??

Comment: Your structure should be declared inside the header and that should be included in both main as well as lib why you are facing problem in this can you please elaborate more??

Comment: There isn't a problem when I include in both header and source, I just think it's a wrong way to do it. The header only needs to be called once from the main.c file isn't it?

Comment: Use multiple inclusion header file check with `#ifndef _LIB_H_ ...`
And include lib.h where structure resides, in both main.c & lib.c

Comment: @Viz a header contains only the declarations and not the definitions . This means you need to include this header in the file where you have defined this and also the file where you want to use this

Comment: @P0W, **do not start names with underscore followed by uppercase letter** -- such names are reserved for the implementation. Please don't advise people to write programs with undefined behaviour!

Comment: @Viz, you do not "call" a header file, you include it. You call a function.

Comment: also read this useful info http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/